# Export command in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash

I am working in SIP based project. The app should support for multiple architecture. So I have to export the following command to give the permission.

```
export LDFLAGS += -march=armv7 -mcpu=arm1176jzf-s -mcpu=cortex-a8
```

But when I run in the Terminal, I am getting following error message. Please tell me how to export the about command in Terminal.

```
-bash: export: `+=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `-march=armv7': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `-mcpu=arm1176jzf-s': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `-mcpu=cortex-a8': not a valid identifier
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

```
export LDFLAGS+=" -march=armv7 -mcpu=arm1176jzf-s -mcpu=cortex-a8"
```